# lie algebras, Kac Moody, and quantum mechanics book

Tags: books, lie-algebras, kac-moody-algebras, quantum-field-theory, quantum-groups

Hi all, I've just finished a graduated course on Kac-Moody algebras, and I'm really looking for some reading in regard to their applications to Quantum Mechanics. Can you help?

Answer (score 2):

I can recommend the article of Louise Dolan, "The Beacon of Kac-
Moody Symmetry for Physics", and the references given therein. From the summary: In addition to (this) wide application to physical theories, the Kac-Moody algebras are also relevant to number theory and modular forms.
The link is http://www.ams.org/notices/199512/dolan.pdf.

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend the book "[Affine Lie Algebras, Weight Multiplicities, and Branching Rules](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0520067681)": a very pleasant reading, both for its math and for its physics content.